# Poisson with two gamma mixture

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, integral

There are three variables, y, $\phi$,$\gamma$, $f_{y,\phi,\gamma}\propto\frac{1}{y!}(\nu\phi\gamma)^y\exp(-\nu\phi\gamma)\exp(-\alpha\phi)\phi^{\alpha-1}\exp(-\gamma)\gamma^n\exp(-\theta\gamma)\gamma^{\theta-1}$

I know that given the rest, $y,\phi,\gamma$ are distributed as Poisson, Gamma, Gamma respectively.

Is there any closed forms of the marginal distribution of $y,\phi,\gamma$?

Answer (score 1):

Since\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty&(\nu\phi\gamma)^y\exp(-\nu\phi\gamma)\exp(-\alpha\phi)\phi^{\alpha-1}\exp(-\gamma)\gamma^n\exp(-\theta\gamma)\gamma^{\theta-1} \text{d}\gamma\\
&=(\nu\phi)^y\exp(-\alpha\phi)\phi^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty\exp(-(1+\theta+\nu\phi)\gamma)\gamma^{n+\theta-1}\text{d}\gamma\\
&=(\nu\phi)^y\exp(-\alpha\phi)\phi^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(n+\theta)(1+\theta+\nu\phi)^{-n-\theta}
\end{align*}there does not appear to be a generic solution for the integrals of the form
$$\int_0^\infty x^a(1+x)^{-b}\exp\{-cx\}\text{d}x$$
(when $b$ is an integer, there are some expressions involving [special functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(x%5E3)%20%20(1%2Bx)%5E(-7)%20exp(-x)from%200%20to%20infinity) but I would not call this a closed-form expression).